# Phase computation in Matlab

Tags: digital-communications

I want t o compute a phase ( angle) of my signal, which is an array of complex numbers.
My code:

```
N = 10000;
M=4;BT = 0.5; Tb = 2;
a = randi([0,1],N,1);
ak = 2*a-1; 
ak_rect = kron(ak,ones(M,1)); 
h_g = gaussfir (BT,Tb,M);
ov_f = conv(h_g,ak_rect,'full');
ov_f = ov_f/max(abs(ov_f));
phi = filter(1,[1,-1],ov_f);
phi = phi *0.5*pi/Tb;  % phase of the signal
I = cos(phi);
Q = sin(phi);
s_e = I - 1i*Q; % My signal: complex numbers
```

I can compute `phi` by using  `atan2(Y,X)` or `angle(s_e)` : `phi_atan2 = atan2(Q, I)` or `angle(s_e)`

if I plot `phi` and `phi_atan2` , they are different

[image]

`phi` and `phi_atan2` should be the same:

For example: given a winkle $\theta$ , we use the same math operation as in matlba code:

1. Compute $Q = \sin (\theta)$
2. Compute $I = \cos(\theta)$
3. `atan2(Y,X)` is $\arctan$.
   $$\tan(\theta) =  \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$$

$$\theta = \arctan( \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the phase:

```
plot(phi)
hold on
plot(unwrap(atan2(Q,I)),'r')
```

yields

[image: Phase plot]

where the two plots precisely overlap each other.

`atan2` can only determine a phase in the range `-pi` to `+pi` radians.  But your `phi` value range is much larger.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it by less than a minute ... :)

Comment: I think the range of `atan2` is between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, not between zero and $2\pi$. Not really important though ...

Comment: @MattL. D'oh! :-)

Comment: is it work as follow:  phi(i)= phi(i) -2pi, if phi(i) >pi , where phi (i) = atan2(Q(i),I(i)) - atan2(Q(i-1),I(i-1)), and phi(i)= phi(i) +2pi, if phi(i) <pi

Comment: @FrHart64 I suggest reading the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) on The Mathworks website and asking a follow-up question if there is something more you need.

Answer (score 1):

An angle doesn't have a unique value, you can always add or subtract integer multiples of $2\pi$ without changing anything, other than the number of times you go around a circle to end up at the same point. Your variable `phi` can take any value, whereas `atan2` gives you the angle's principal value in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.